# Sublime 3: When trying to run/compile Python code, "python: command not found" errors are being returned

Tags: python3, sublime-text

I am using Sublime 3 as my text editor, and am working with a python file.  Whenever I try and run the script or compile it through Sublime, I get the following error output:

```
bash: python: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: python -m py_compile "/home/ubuntu/PYTHON_SCRIPTS/hello.py"]
[dir: /home/ubuntu/PYTHON_SCRIPTS]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin]
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: i am using 18.04 lettest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 does not install Python 2 by default, and Sublime is currently trying to use that.

`python` is for Python 2, which is no longer installed; you ideally should be configuring Sublime to use Python 3 and the `python3` executable.

If you really are still writing code for Python 2, you need to install Python 2.

```
sudo apt install python-all
```

Once this completes it should resolve the problems you're seeing.  However, you really should be using Python 3, not Python 2.

Comment: i tried it but still the same errors are there

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson you may need your own question/post for this, because we need a lot more information than you've got here.  If you are on 20.04 it requires *more* work to make Python 2 exist.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can try below command instead of sudo apt-get install python3

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

Because in Ubuntu 20.04 when you install sublime it uses older version of python so if you install normal python it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you already have python3 installed.

first remove python2 by using the following command line.

```
$ sudo apt purge -y python2.7-minimal
```

then use the following command line.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

check the version of your current python

```
$ python --version
```

it will show you that it is python3.
you can do the same with pip if you are fond of installing through pip